# Script to call either from file or user input

Tags: shell, unix, input

I'm trying to write a small script that either takes input from a file or from user, then it gets rid of any blank lines from it.

I'm trying to make it so that if there is no file name specified it will prompt the user for input. Also is the best way to output the manual input to a file then run the code or to store it in a variable?

So far I have this but when I run it with a file it give 1 line of error before returning the output I want. The error says `./deblank: line 1: [blank_lines.txt: command not found`

```
if [$@ -eq "$NO_ARGS"]; then  
cat > temporary.txt; sed '/^$/d' <temporary.txt  
else  
sed '/^$/d' <$@  
fi
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need spaces around `[` and `]`.  In bash, `[` is a *command* and you need spaces around it for bash to interpret it so.

You can also check for the presence of arguments by using `(( ... ))`.  So your script could be rewritten as:

```
if ((!$#)); then
  cat > temporary.txt; sed '/^$/d' <temporary.txt
else
  sed '/^$/d' "$@"
fi
```

If you want to use only the first argument, then you need to say `$1` (and not `$@`).

Comment: LOL i got it working with ` if [ $# -lt 1 ] ` but your code makes much more sense lol, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then  
  cat > temporary.txt; sed '/^$/d' <temporary.txt  
else  
  cat $@ | sed '/^$/d'  
fi
```

A space is needed between `[` and `$@` and your usage of `$@` is not good. `$@` represents all arguments and `-eq` is used to compare numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here:

1. You need to leave a space between the square brackets [ ] and the variables.
2. When using a string type, you cannot use -eq, use == instead.
3. When using a string comparison you need to use double square brackets.

So the code should look like:

```
if [[ "$@" == "$NO_ARGS" ]]; then
cat > temporary.txt; sed '/^$/d' <temporary.txt
else
sed '/^$/d' <$@
fi
```

Or else use $# instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forcing user input to a file, I'd force the given file to stdin:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1  &&  -r $1 ]]; then
    # it's a file
    exec 0<"$1"
elif ! tty -s; then
    : # input is piped from stdin
else
    # get input from user
    echo "No file specified, please enter your input, ctrl-D to end"   
fi

# now, let sed read from stdin
sed '/^$/d'
```